# Sqlite manipulates the string out of the database

Tags: python, html, sqlite

In my login method I'm trying to check wether the password in the database corresponds to the password submitted by the user. I use this code:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
error = None
db = get_db()
if request.method == 'POST':
    cur = db.execute('select password from users where username = ?', (request.form['username'], ))
    password = cur.fetchone()
    print password
    print request.form['password']
    if request.form['password'] != password:
        error = 'Invalid username/password combination'
    else:
        session['logged_in'] = True
        flash('You were logged in')
        return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))
return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```

For example when the password is default, this what the print commands show me:

```
print password : (u'default',)
print request.form['password'] : default
```

So they are indeed not equal. Does anybody knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each row returned by the database is a tuple of columns. You retrieved one row (`.fetchone()`) and that row is a tuple with one element (you selected only the `password` column). Simply take it *out* from the tuple using it's index:

```
password = cur.fetchone()[0]
```